# Full-time, dedicated editors on SO?

Tags: discussion, edits, users

Some questions are edited as soon as they're posted on the trilogy. Instantaneously even.

It's as if they are pounced upon by a legion of editors and proofreaders, hungry dictionary and grammar wolves, baying at the gates ready to clean up and fix typos and formatting blocks.

Is there a dedicated band, full-time editors you may say, who help edit the posts on Stack Overflow?

Comment: For reference, it was Duran Duran.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Anyone over 2000 rep (only 100 rep if you're talking about Community wiki posts) with a desire to not have their eyeballs and sense of English assaulted.

Comment: you have demonstrated it completely by editing my question. :)

Comment: and I have demonstrated it by editing his!

Comment: Nothing left for me to demonstrate... :(

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, those who're editing will see the same message one sees when editing one's own post. The last point seems [to be forgotten](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/38242/revisions) on meta every now and then... ;-)

> **How to Edit**
>
> ► fix grammatical or spelling errors
> ► clarify meaning without changing it
> ► correct minor mistakes
> ► add related resources or links
> ► always respect the original author

Comment: The respect paid was in how much greater his question is now.

Comment: That's definitely true :-)